# Unable to install JHipster

Tags: java, node.js, npm, jhipster

I am trying to install JHipster on a Mac M1 (Ventura). Unfortunately, I am encountering difficulties in completing the installation successfully. I have already installed Node.js version 18.17.1 and Java 17 on my system. I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this matter[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jHipster first by this command:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

Then you can invoke:

```
jhipster --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a setup issue of your shell, as a workaround you could run `npx jhipster` rather than only `jhipster`